# Slow Webpack & Webpack-dev-server builds

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My webpack & webpack-dev-server builds are excruiatingly slow. I'll list my package.json, webpack build configurations, and stats below. I've tried removing a bunch of useless node modules, using the DLL Plugin (to no avail), Common Chunks, Caching Node Modules. Nothing seems to work. I also have no relevant global npm packages (if that makes a difference). Initial build times are slower when running webpack-dev-server (as are rebuild) than using regular old webpack (although that's slow also).

**It's quite odd. Sometimes my app builds (using webpack-dev-server) in ~15 seconds, sometimes it takes 10+ minutes.**  Usually slow, very rarely does it take a few seconds.

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress --profile --json > stats.json",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack/dev.config.js --hot --colors",
    "dev:stats": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack/dev.config.js --hot --colors --progress --profile",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node bin/prod.js"
  },
...
```

My configurations are split by **base**, **dev**, and **prod**. Here are my base and dev configs.

**base.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.join(__dirname, '/../src/'),
      lib: path.join(__dirname, '/../lib/'),
    },
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: 'babel-loader', },
      { test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.(png)(\?.*|)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=2000000&name=[name].[ext]' },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'node-static',
      filename: 'node-static.js',
      minChunks(module, count) {
        const context = module.context;
        return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

**dev.config.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseConfig = require('./base.config');
const FlowWebpackPlugin = require('flow-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
  devtool: false,
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: 'src',
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:9000',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        exclude: [/node_modules/],

      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',

      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new FlowWebpackPlugin(),
  ]
});
```

**build stats**

```
> NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack/dev.config.js --hot --colors --progress --profile


Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from src
404s will fallback to /index.html
10616ms building modules                                                                s
9ms sealing
0ms optimizing
0ms basic module optimization
2ms module optimization
0ms advanced module optimization
9ms basic chunk optimization
0ms chunk optimization
0ms advanced chunk optimization
3ms module and chunk tree optimization
0ms chunk modules optimization
0ms advanced chunk modules optimization
32ms module reviving
1ms module order optimization
2ms module id optimization
0ms chunk reviving
0ms chunk order optimization
15ms chunk id optimization
17ms hashing
0ms module assets processing
56ms chunk assets processing
18ms additional chunk assets processing
0ms recording
0ms additional asset processing
0ms chunk asset optimization
150ms asset optimization
159ms emitting
Hash: 5ca0087e7e73b7089262
Version: webpack 3.8.1
Time: 105465ms
         Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
     bundle.js     204 kB       0  [emitted]         main
node-static.js    2.37 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  node-static
    index.html  553 bytes          [emitted]
   [0] ./node_modules/react/react.js 56 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:283ms building:85ms = 368ms
  [33] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js 925 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:361ms building:14ms = 375ms
 [280] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
        factory:1ms building:1ms = 2ms
 [281] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 7.95 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:25ms building:24ms dependencies:2990ms = 3039ms
 [282] (webpack)/node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:22ms building:3024ms = 3046ms
 [288] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:6997ms building:14ms = 7011ms
 [290] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.74 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:6999ms building:46ms = 7045ms
 [291] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:22ms building:2995ms = 3017ms
 [293] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.73 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:22ms building:3000ms = 3022ms
 [298] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:12ms building:9ms dependencies:3029ms = 3050ms
 [300] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.56 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:55ms building:13ms = 68ms
 [301] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.27 kB {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:3031ms building:3944ms dependencies:0ms = 6975ms
 [302] ./src/index.js 865 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:73ms building:6772ms = 6845ms
 [473] ./src/components/App/App.jsx 801 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:202ms building:77ms dependencies:5ms = 284ms
 [714] ./src/store.js 697 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:202ms building:64ms = 266ms
    + 705 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
       [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 838 bytes {0} [built]
            factory:23ms building:44ms = 67ms
       [1] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:3004ms building:3974ms = 6978ms
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 488 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:9ms building:14ms = 23ms
       [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 495 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:9ms building:14ms = 23ms
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Build time was slowed by the FlowWebpackPlugin. Build time went from 10 minutes to 10 seconds after I removed the plugin. Will disable for now.